# Why is Spacy sentiment score 0.0 for a sentence?

Tags: nlp, sentiment-analysis, language-model, spacy

I'm trying to get a sentence's sentiment score using Spacy and apparently every sentence I pass gets a score of 0.0. Can someone help me understand what's going wrong here?

```
import spacy

nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_sm")
doc1 = nlp("This Movie is really Great!")
doc2 = nlp("This Movie was the Worst!")

print("Sentiment score for 1st Sentence ",doc1.sentiment)
print("Sentiment score for 2nd Sentence ",doc2.sentiment)

for token in doc1:
    print(token.text, token.pos_, token.dep_)


for token in doc2:
    print(token.text, token.pos_, token.dep_)
```

Which gives the output as:

```
Sentiment score for 1st Sentence  0.0
Sentiment score for 2nd Sentence  0.0
This DET det
Movie PROPN nsubj
is AUX ROOT
really ADV advmod
Great ADJ acomp
! PUNCT punct
This DET det
Movie PROPN nsubj
was AUX ROOT
the DET det
Worst ADJ attr
! PUNCT punct
```

Spacy's documentation says this about `Doc.sentiment`:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default Spacy English model `en_core_web_sm` does not support sentiment analysis (despite class [`Doc`](https://spacy.io/api/doc) having a `sentiment` property).

To add a sentiment analysis component to your Spacy pipeline, you can use the [TextBlob](https://github.com/sloria/TextBlob) library, by means of the [spacytextblob](https://github.com/SamEdwardes/spacytextblob) Spacy component:

```
import spacy
from spacytextblob.spacytextblob import SpacyTextBlob

nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_sm')
text = "I had a really horrible day. It was the worst day ever! But every now and then I have a really good day that makes me happy."
nlp.add_pipe("spacytextblob")
doc = nlp(text)

print(doc._.blob.polarity)
# -0.125

print(doc._.blob.subjectivity)
# 0.9

print(doc._.blob.sentiment_assessments.assessments)
# [(['really', 'horrible'], -1.0, 1.0, None), (['worst', '!'], -1.0, 1.0, None), (['really', 'good'], 0.7, 0.6000000000000001, None), (['happy'], 0.8, 1.0, None)]
```

Comment: Thanks this is really helpful! I'll play around further with this; I'm interested in getting an aggregated score for each sentence and use it to determine the sentiment of the sentence.